# How do I get the guards to stop attacking me, and get them to arrest me?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I broke out of jail, and my bounty is high. I'd like to pay it off. 
How do I get them to stop attacking me so I can pay them.

Comment: I think once you've broken out of jail, the guards are going to be hostile to you in that area for a little while.  Try going to another town and resting in a bed for a few days before returning.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get them to stop attacking you are

- Kill Them.
- Run away from town and return later after some time. The higher your bounty, the longer it takes for them to stop attacking you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont kill them because then you are charged with murder and it will take longer for the bounty to go away. Just run away do a quest or something and come back and everything should be fine.